# Появление объекта с задержкой времени

Tags: javascript

Доброго всем времени суток

На странице есть кое какой объект (картинка, таблица... неважно). При загрузке страницы охота не показывать этот объект, а показать с задержкой с указанным интервалом времени (3 сек). Ну в идеале, что бы еще сам объект появлялся не мгновенно, а скажем 1 секунду. Подскажите, как такое реализовать?

Comment: `setTimeout` и `fadeIn` вам в помощь

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если использовать jQuery, то:

```
$(function(){                // сработает, когда документ загрузится
    $('#someID').delay(3000) // пауза в 3 сек.
                .show(1000); // появление элемента в течении 1 сек.
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Или можно использовать  `setTimeout()`. [settimeout](http://javascript.ru/settimeout)

Как удобней будет.

Comment: setTimeout() не плавно покажет, а через определенное время сразу покажет объект и эффекта не будет.
Что бы было плавно нужно писать функцию, или же юзать дж квери.

Comment: Ах, извините) Вы сказали с задержкой, вот вам задержка, Ну а ка он появится это уже можно в вызываемой функции можете определить, пусть хоть сначала обнаженная девушка появиться, а после ваша информация) Я же сказал, как вариант)