# Как изменить фон таблицы с задержкой?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Доброго всем дня!

Есть табличка. У таблички есть `class`, который равен кое чему. Как сделать так, что бы при загрузке страницы `class` был равен одному значению, а по прошествии некоторого времени менялся на другой (хочется плавно сменить фон).

Поиск, конечно, рулит, и я [кое что нашел](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/132823/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8) но, к сожалению, моих знаний не достаточно, чтобы переписать это на свой лад. Подскажите, как быть?

p.s. как мне охота влепить акцепт, но спустя столько проб и ошибок вопрос продвинулся только чуть чуть.

jQuery UI с компонентом Effects Core установлен

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<table id="tut">
...
</table>

<script>
setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('tut').className += ' newClass';}, 3000);
</script>
```

Через 3 секунды к таблице добавится класс `newClass`. Если надо фон сменить плаааавно, то проще подключить jQuery, jQuery UI и воспользоваться [анимацией классов](http://jqueryui.com/demos/switchClass/).

Comment: функция сработала. анимацию для фона сработала, а для функцию в целом применить не получилось

    setTimeout(function().animate({
 
 document.getElementById('tut').className += ' myclass_new';
 
 },3000);, 3000);

Comment: При подключенных библиотеках анимация запускается так:

    setTimeout(function(){$('#tut').toggleClass('oldClass', 'newClass', 1000);}, 3000);

Через 3 секунды пойдет анимация смены классов, которая будет длиться 1 секунду.

Comment: @ling, у `[.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)` параметры чуть-чуть другие

Comment: jQuery UI с компонентом Effects Core установлен?  
[http://jqueryui.com/download][1]

[1]: http://jqueryui.com/download

Comment: установил. паразительно, я увидел как все на моей странице сдвинулось в центр, при этом должного эффекта не произошло. попробовал онлайн - тоже ничего http://jsfiddle.net/A2B8J/

Comment: @Spectre, точно. Там должна быть функция switchClass().

Answer (score 3):

```
function table(){
$('.one').removeClass('one').addClass('two');
}  
​setTimeout(table,2000);​
```

[Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/shanhaichik/y2NGp/8/)

Если нужно плавно, то можно использовать [.animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Подключаем jQuery UI 1.8.18.
Пишем:

```
$('.one').stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "#40B8FE"}, 3000);​
```

Смотрим: [Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/shanhaichik/6X72Q/1/)

Или
    function table(){
    $('.one').stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "#40B8FE"}, 3000);​
    }
    ​setTimeout(table,2000);​

Comment: собственно код прост и легко читаем, но при загрузке у меня ничего не происходит. т.е. фон там сразу синий (а должен быть с переходом с красного на синий). O_o

Comment: вы еще раз по ссылке примера зайдите, я не ту скинул сначала)

Comment: Можно вот так, но единственное что это вместе с содержимым обновляется.
http://jsfiddle.net/shanhaichik/EF9RH/

function table(){
    $('.one').animate({opacity: 0}, 1000, "linear", function(){
    $(this).css("background","#CCCCCC").animate({opacity: 1}, 1000);
    })
       
}  
setTimeout(table,2000);​

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/shanhaichik/6X72Q/1/ dвот такой вариант должен подойти.
Главное подключить еще одну библиотечку jQuery UI 1.8.18.

Comment: function table(){ 
$('.one').stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "#40B8FE"}, 3000).toggleClass("one two");​​​​​ 
}
​setTimeout(table,2000);​

Comment: все супер. только анимация идет рывком, т.е. ее нет http://jsfiddle.net/6X72Q/6/

Answer (score 1):

На странице, ссылку на которую Вы дали. все написано

```
$(function(){                                  // сработает, когда документ загрузится
.delay(3000)           // пауза в 3 сек а потом смена класа.
$("#ид обьекта класс которого меняем").removeClass("myClass noClass").addClass("yourClass");                    // удаляет и присваивает класс обьекту 
});
```

В примере выше показано изменение класса элемента

Если не понятно, то вот офф. мануал

- [removeClass](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)
- [addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)

P.S можете попробовать как вариант

```
setTimeout(function() { $('#foo').fadeOut(); }, 5000);
```

Только замените в ней `fadeout` на присвоить класс и удалить

Comment: это чё такое?

    $(function(){
    .delay(3000)